# Can you encode values expressed as binary digits directly in the c-family of languages?

Tags: c, encoding, binary, constants

In the c-based (or c-inspired) family of languages (i.e. C/C++/Objective-C/JavaScript) when typing a constant number, you can simply type the number directly for its decimal value, or you can prefix it with `0x` to write it via hexadecimal. JavaScript lets you even type values using Octal encoding by prefixing the number with a zero (...which is completely bonkers to me since 09 looks to be 9 but actually parses to zero!  Way to confuse people! Should've been `8x` prefix or similar, but I digress...)

What I'm wondering is if there's an equivalent for typing things directly in binary.

For instance, I'd love to see something like this:

```
int x = Bx00001001; // x would equal 9, (bits 8 and 1 are set)
int x = 1x00001001; // Alternate prefix '1x' instead of 'Bx'
```

Just for fun, I'm actually considering writing a *pre*-pre-compiler to do exactly that, but again just for fun since it of course the code wouldn't be portable.

Still, hoping there's a standards-way to do this.  Granted, yes, it's very easy to just encode in hex (you only need to learn up to 15 after all), but again, just wondering more out of curiosity.

But really... what the heck is up with that Octal nonsense!! Crazy if you ask me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no binary constants in Standard C.

Standard C only has decimal (no prefix), octal (`0` prefix) and hexadecimal (`0x` or `0X` prefix) constants. GNU C provides binary constants as a GNU extension to C, see:

**6.60 Binary constants using the `0b' prefix**

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html

Comment: And here I was thinking that Octal prefix was only Jacascript.  MAN, I can't stand that!  014 is a valid decimal number since by definition, leading zeroes are ignored!  I hate double-interpretation.  There is no way 0o22 could be misinterpreted as a decimal.  Why didn't they give it such a prefix! ...but  I digress!  You get the vote because of the GCC ref.  Since it's GCC, I wonder if Apple supports it in Objective-C!

Answer (score 1):

In C++11, you could accomplish this by using a [user-defined literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#User-defined_literals) (though you have to define a *suffix* rather than a prefix).

> JavaScript lets you even type values using Octal encoding by prefixing the number with a zero […] what the heck is up with that Octal nonsense!

Yes, that's also true of C, and other C-derived languages. From what I understand, octal was more popular than hex among users of [18-bit architectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-bit) (since a word would be exactly 6 octal digits; obviously 4.5 hex digits is a bit awkward). But that was before my time. ;-)

Comment: Octal was useful on old DEC machines like the PDP-11 because the fields in the opcodes were aligned on 3 bit/octal digit boundaries. C was invented on a DEC machine, so the useful octal literals were incorporated into the C language.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of just putting binary constants into code. But why do you need to? It is easy to convert binary into hex. Just group the binary number into groups of 4. Each group of 4 represents one hex digit. i.e.

0000 -> 0, 0001 -> 1, ....1001 -> 9, 1010 -> A, ... 1111 -> F

Comment: I explicitly called out using hex in my question as the correct way to do that. That's C 101 stuff.  Again, as I said, I don't *need* to.  I was wondering could it be done. For instance, if I say 'What are the common bits between 0x3C and 0x7D from a readability standpoint, it's not easy to tell.  But if I showed 2x00001001 and 2x10001000, visually I can see quickly that the fourth LSB is common.  Again, this was just a 'Hey, can it', not a 'should it'.